# Probability Range?

Tags: probability

How do you find the range ( min and max) for a probability function such as $$\frac{P (B|A) − P (B)} {1−P (B)}\;?$$

What I tried was to use Venn diagrams, but I couldn't find a solution as the circles must overlap completely to max P (B|A). But that causes P(B) to decrease.

Any thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: Presumably you have some concrete problem in mind.  Without further information, $P(B|A)$ could be $0$, or it could be $1$, or anywhere in between. The ratio you wrote down could be huge negative. It is never greater than $1$. If there are additional details that you know, perhaps a more explicit answer could be supplied.

Comment: That is all to the question. the value of P(B|A) can be anything. So the upper bound of the equation is 1. How would one solve to a possible lower bound. Thank you.

Comment: I will give an answer to the lower bound issue, because it is unpleasant to type it as a series of comments.

Comment: When does the probability function get its minimum and
maximum values.

Comment: I am concerned about your use of the term "probability function."  For a probability function, you would need first of all a sample space.  And as has been observed in my comments and answer, the expression you gave can in some situations be negative. Then certainly it cannot be interpreted as a probability.

Comment: @Jimmy: $P(B|A)=\frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)}$, so $P(B|A)$ can range from $0$ to $1$. So a lower limit to the expression would be $\frac{-P(B)}{1-P(B)}$, which is negative, as André commented.

Comment: $P(B)$ is bounded above by $\max\{P(B\mid A), P(B\mid A^c)\}$ and bounded below by $\min\{P(B\mid A), P(B\mid A^c\}$.

Answer (score 3):

**No lower bound**: We give an example to show that the expression 
$$\frac{P(B|A)-P(B)}{1-P(B)}$$
can be arbitrarily large negative.

Imagine tossing a very unfair coin which has probability of head equal to $10^{-6}$, and therefore probability of tail equal to $1-10^{-6}$.

Let $B$ be the event "tail" and let $A$ the event "head."  It is clear that $P(B|A)=0$.
Thus our expression is equal to 
$$\frac{0 -(1-10^{-6})}{1-(1-10^{-6})}.$$
This simplifies to $-999999$.

By choosing $10^{-66}$ instead of $10^{-6}$, we can make our expression inconceivably huge negative.  So there is no universal lower bound for our expression.  (If suitable restrictions are put on $B$ and $A$, there may be a lower bound.)

**An upper bound**: Choose any $A$ such that $P(B|A)=1$, for example choose $A=B$.  Then our expression is equal to $1$.  It cannot ever be larger than $1$, since for given $P(B)$, the numerator is maximized if $A$ is such that $P(B|A)=1$.  Thus $1$ is an upper bound for our expression. This upper bound can be attained, so there is no cheaper universal upper bound.

Comment: Thank you for that great analysis. 
I was wondering what is A -> B?

Comment: Your meaning is not clear to me.  One can make sense of $A \implies B$ in a probabilistic context, but you would have to frame a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

As another way of looking at André Nicolas's solution, note that your expression is the same as  $$1-\dfrac{\Pr(\text{not }B|A)}{\Pr(\text{not }B)}$$  where the quotient can take any non-negative value and so the whole expression can take any value from 1 downwards including any negative value.

As he says in a comment, this may be a function of probabilities but it is not a probability itself.